# Remote Powershell Install Issue

Tags: powershell, remote-access

I am trying to automate installations remotely using powershell and I have multiple pieces working, the last piece that is not working is after I remote in, I copy files just fine but when I try to execute a PS script I fails with the same error.  Script and error is listed below:

```html
Enable-WSManCredSSP -Role Client -DelegateComputer $SQL_Server -Force 
 $cred = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential $Secure_SQLInstaller, $Secure_SQLInstallerPassword

 $Batch_exec = "\\demo.dev\SI\Start.ps1"

 $Argument_list = "$SV, $SE, $DC, $SA, $SP, $SAP, $FP, $DT, $PSN, $E"

 Invoke-Command -ComputerName $SQL_Server -Authentication CredSSP -credential $cred -FilePath $Batch_exec -scriptblock { Start-Process -FilePath $Batch_exec -ArgumentList $Argument_list }


Invoke-Command : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.
At line:110 char:2
+  Invoke-Command -ComputerName $SQL_Server -Authentication CredSSP -credential $c ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-Command], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameterSet,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeCommandCommand
```

Comment: Also, I know Argument_list has commas for an array but even if I take them out because I am calling a function, I get the same error.  Just wanted to make a note of that.  Thank you for any assistance.

Comment: Pretty sure it is because you are using `-FilePath`  _and_  `-scriptblock`

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure it's telling you that it's an ambiguous parameter set because you've specified both -FilePath and -Sciptblock. You've got to pick one or the other, so:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $SQL_Server -Authentication CredSSP -credential $cred  -scriptblock { Start-Process -FilePath $Batch_exec -ArgumentList $Argument_list }
```

OR

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $SQL_Server -Authentication CredSSP -credential $cred -FilePath $Batch_exec
```

For more information look at the parameter sets of [`Invoke-Command`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849719.aspx). You will see they are mutually exclusive.

Comment: I tried the first option and I get: Cannot validate argument on parameter 'FilePath'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the 
command again.

Comment: Tried the second option and get: I tried the first option and I get: Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null; The expression after '.' in a pipeline element produced an object that was not valid. It must result in a command name, a script block, or a 
CommandInfo object. which could be because I am going to a different domain.

Comment: Try creating that string with single quotes, like this:  $Batch_exec = '\\demo.dev\SI\Start.ps1' ?

Comment: Also, you could have a scoping issue trying to use $Batch_exec in your script block like that.

Comment: Tried single quotes and that did not work, same error.  Had $Batch_exec in script block and received error Cannot validate argument on parameter 'FilePath'.

Comment: Yeah I know, the fact that you're trying to use $Batch_exec in the script block IS the problem. It's out of scope I would say.

Comment: And have you verified that path assigne to $Batch_exec is actually reachable? like have you try just doing, Get-ChildItem $Batch_exec?

Comment: As I recall that will work if executing a .bat file but maybe not ps1?  Will have to figure this out.  There is a PS session locally tomorrow but cannot attend and this is one of their topics.  I have another employee attending so hopefully they can retrieve some good info.  Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: Ahhhhhh!  you might be right with Get-ChildItem $Batch_exec, it is trying to hit the local environment and not the remote environment.  Let me review this some more.